# Saving to Active Directory - Access Is Denied for Domain Admin

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory

I'm working on a C# Web Application to allow read and write access to Active Directory user accounts.

I have got this working great on our main company AD- I can read accounts, get attributes, save details back to AD, enable/disable accounts etc. I'm using impersonation to do this, so just before it saves to AD it changes to using a different account (which belongs to Domain Admins), then reverts to the main app pool account after saving.

I've just been given the requirement to add user accounts through the app, but I'm not happy about testing this on the main AD, and I've therefore setup a VM with a test AD. I've got the app setup on that VM, and it reads from AD fine. I've setup the same user account that I impersonate on the live AD, and have added it to the domain admins group. However, when I try to save details to an existing user I get an "Access is Denied" error.

I know the impersonation is working as just before saving I output the result, and I tried changing the password and it failed with a different error.

I've asked our Network Administrator if he's setup anything special on the impersonation user for the live AD, but he says he hasn't, and they appear to be identical.

Does anyone know of anything else I might need to do other than add the impersonation user to the domain admins group? I've tried logging into the VM as the user, and have made a change to a user account through AD itself, so the user does seem to have the required level of access.

The following is the code I'm using to impersonate the user:

```
Impersonation imp = new Impersonation();
string impResult = "";
imp.ImpersonateDomainUser(out impResult, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ADAdminUserLogin"], user.Domain, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ADAdminUserPwd"]);
...

imp.Revert();
```

`impResult` returns the following:

```
Before impersonation: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM 
After impersonation: TESTDOMAIN\user.manager.service
```

The code I'm using to save to AD is:

```
var entry = new DirectoryEntry();
var account = userName.Replace(domain, "");

var search = new DirectorySearcher(entry) { Filter = "(SAMAccountName=" + account + ")" };
search.PropertiesToLoad.Add(propertyName);

var result = search.FindOne();

if (result != null)
{
   DirectoryEntry entryToUpdate = result.GetDirectoryEntry();

   if (propertyValue == null || propertyValue.ToString().Length == 0)
      entryToUpdate.Properties[propertyName].Clear();
   else
      entryToUpdate.Properties[propertyName].Value = propertyValue;

   entryToUpdate.CommitChanges();

   entryToUpdate.Close();
   entryToUpdate.Dispose();
}
```

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: I've added some tracing to my app to ensure that at the point its actually saving the property to AD its using the impersonated user account, and this is the case.

Comment: I appear to have fixed it now.

If anyone else has this issue, which is unlikely unless you are also testing on a VM, it was down to my User Access Control settings. I turned UAC off and rebooted, and its now working.

Comment: Please your comment as an answer, and flag it as valid answer.

Answer (score 4):

This issue was down to User Access Control settings on the Virtual Machine.

Once I disabled User Access Control through the control panel, I was then able to save users to Active Directory. Its possible that running the browser as administrator may have also worked, though I didn't try this.